# How to provide highlevel API call Security - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, security, proxy, charles-proxy

As for normal api calls, it will be able to track using network debugging proxy such as Charles.

So up data and down data was encrypted to avoid the same.

But when I check some apps it hides the url of api too. How to achieve the same in iOS.

Example:

[image]

Note: Also checked by adding ssl certificate in my phone. Still it doesn't shown.

Answer (score 8):

This mechanism is called SSL **Pinning**.

*Theory:*

> **What is Pinning?** .
>
> Pinning is an optional mechanism that can be used to improve the
>   security of a service or site that relies on SSL Certificates. Pinning
>   allows you to specify a cryptographic identity that should be accepted
>   by users visiting your site.
>
> That sounds complex, but it’s actually pretty simple. Let’s start by
>   breaking down that down:
>
> A cryptographic identity is a file that can prove the identity of a
>   server/host through cryptography. An SSL certificate, a public key,
>   and a CSR are all examples of a cryptographic identity. That pin would
>   then tell the client to remember that identity (or identities) and
>   only accept those when establishing future secure connections.
>
> So, if you wanted to use pinning, you would configure your server (in
>   some situations – think internal systems – you may also configure the
>   clients) and specify what you wanted to pin. Browsers and other
>   clients would evaluate the pinned identity on every connection. If any
>   other identity was presented, the client would abort the connection
>   (**which was happened in your case with Charles Proxy**).
>
> To think big picture: an SSL connection tells the client to make an
>   encrypted connection with any identity matching that host. Pinning
>   tells the client a specific identity they should accept when making a
>   secure connection.
>
> So, for example, if our site is example.com, we could pin an identity.
>   When a user visits our site, they would receive the pinned
>   information. On a future visit, their browser would take action if we
>   tried to get the client to use a different identity.

*Practice:*

The main key of SSL pinning that server certificate will be saved in app bundle. Then, when client receives certificate from server, it then compares 2 certificates to make sure that they are the same before establishing the connection.

The [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) HTTP networking library has the built-in function for SSL pinning and very easy to use:

```
let pathToCert = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "name-of-cert-file", ofType: "cer")
let localCertificate: NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: pathToCert!)!

let serverTrustPolicy = ServerTrustPolicy.pinCertificates(
    certificates: [SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, localCertificate)!],
    validateCertificateChain: true,
    validateHost: true
)

let serverTrustPolicies = [
    "my-server.com": serverTrustPolicy
]

let sessionManager = SessionManager(
    serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
)
```

You can read more [here](https://infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/how-to-make-your-ios-apps-more-secure-with-ssl-pinning) and [here](https://medium.com/@dzungnguyen.hcm/ios-ssl-pinning-bffd2ee9efc) about how to achieve SSL Pinning in your swift app.

Comment: What if we change certificate ? We need to upload app again. I need it to be dynamic completely. How ?

Comment: @UdayKumarEega Yes need to upload the app again and the app will not functions properly till a new update.

Comment: Or you can add the ability to download from the server. I don't know is it the proper way or not, but I implemented in my one app due to the same issue